# How to append a Date filtering condition to my existing filtering codes in R?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset

I need to create a subset of my main data frame (mydata1) in R.

The Date column in mydata1 has already been formatted as a Date using the following codes:

```
mydata1$Date = as.Date(mydata1$Date)
```

I have the current codes running to create the subset of my data:

```
mydata3 <- mydata1 %>%
filter(Total.Extras.Per.GN >= 100) %>%
filter(Original.Meal.Plan.Code %in% target) %>%
filter(Date, between ("2017-01-01"), ("2017-06-01")) %>%
select(PropertyCode, Date, Market, Original.Meal.Plan.Code, GADR, Total.Extras.Per.GN)
```

However, the line `filter(Date, between ("2017-01-01"), ("2017-06-01")) %>%` is giving me an error. How do I write it properly so that it filters my Date column with the dates specified therein?

Error message:
  Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : 
  argument "left" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place *Date* inside the *between* arg and wrap date strings in `as.Date()` for comparison:

```
mydata3 <- mydata1 %>%
   filter(Total.Extras.Per.GN >= 100) %>%
   filter(Original.Meal.Plan.Code %in% target) %>%
   filter(between(Date, as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-06-01"))) %>%
   select(PropertyCode, Date, Market, Original.Meal.Plan.Code, GADR, Total.Extras.Per.GN)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.